# How to include character in new string if x is a multiple of ord(ch)?

Tags: python

So the problem is I need to take a string and if it's ord value (ord(ch)) is a multiple of x in the function then that character needs to be added to the new string. I was just wondering if I've done this correctly?

```
def test(string, x):
    r = []
    for ch in string:
        if ord(ch) % x == 0:
            r.append(ch)
    return ''.join(r)
```

Have I done this correctly? If not, any pointers? This was a question in my test I've failed and I don't know if I did it right or not.

Comment: What do you think? Is it doing what it should? Did you test it?

Comment: seems correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps they were looking for a list comprehension:

```
return "".join( ch for ch in string if ord(ch)%x == 0 )
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks correct. You might want to post the exact instructions for the problem, as it's possible you slightly misread the question. It's very hard to write (and read) unambiguous instructions for coding challenges. Nearly everybody who learned programming has made such a mistake at least once in their life.

I was gonna post a list comprehension version, but Alain T. beat me to it while I formulated this response.